# Is There a Name for this Pattern

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, integration-patterns

I've used this pattern many times in a variety of places, usually alongside a plugin pattern.

Some example ways I've used it are for messaging systems, such as creating subscribers to various types of unrelated messages. I've also used it for generic integration workflows that each need a differently shaped context object.

Basically the pattern consists of defining a blank marker interface for a message or context. Then defining a high level workflow interface that works with the message/context interface. You can then use a factory to get a concrete instance of the workflow, and if needed, the workflow can also be responsible for parsing its message / context from a common data format.

Next, you create an abstract generic base workflow whose responsibilty is just to map calls to the interface methods, which pass around the useless marker interface, into calls to abstract methods that take the concrete version of the message/context.

Hopefully that makes sense. I'll provide a code example below. I'd love to know if this pattern has a name because I've noticed that I've used it about 4-5 times now. Also, I'm just fleshing out how to explain the pattern, so if anything about my explanation doesn't make sense please let me know that as well.

The main point is that you can have multiple classes with different method signatures that can still be called via a common interface:

**End Result**

```
public class ConcreteA : Base<MessageA>
{
    public void Process(MessageA message){...}
    public MessageA Parse(IDictionary data){...}
}

public class ConcreteB : Base<MessageB>
{
    public void Process(MessageB message){...}
    public MessageB Parse(IDictionary data){...}
}

//And both can by called by...
public void Main(){
    var data = GetDataFromIntegrationSource(someContext);
    IWorkflow impl = Factory.GetConcrete(someContext);

    //So in your classes you're able to work with strongly typed parameters,
    //But in the consuming code you still can use a common interface
    //Consuming code never even knows what the strong type is. 
    IMessage msg = impl.Parse(data);
    impl.Process(msg);
}
```

**FULL EXAMPLE**

**High Level Interfaces**

```
public interface IGenericeMarkerInterface
{
}

public interface IGenericWorkflow
{
    void Process(IGenericeMarkerInterface messageOrContext);

    IGenericeMarkerInterface Parse(IDictionary<string, string> commonDataFormat);
}
```

**Abstract Base for Mapping to Concrete Methods**

```
public abstract class GenericWorkflowBase<T> : IGenericWorkflow where T : IGenericeMarkerInterface
{
    public void Process(IGenericeMarkerInterface messageOrContext)
    {
        Process((T)messageOrContext);      
    }

    public IGenericeMarkerInterface Parse(IDictionary<string, string> commonDataFormat)
    {
        return DoParse(commonDataFormat);
    }

    public abstract void Process(T messageOrContext);
    public abstract T DoParse(IDictionary<string, string> commonDataFormat);
}
```

**Mapping Attributes**

```
public class MappingAttributeUsedByFactoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public WorkflowType SomePropertyForMapping { get; set; }
}
```

**Concrete Implementations**

```
public class SomeRandomlyShapedMessageOrContext : IGenericeMarkerInterface
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

[MappingAttributeUsedByFactory(WorkflowType.IntegrationPartnerB)]
public class ConcreteWorkflow : GenericWorkflowBase<SomeRandomlyShapedMessageOrContext>
{
    public override void Process(SomeRandomlyShapedMessageOrContext messageOrContext)
    {
        //TODO: process the strongly typed message
    }

    public override SomeRandomlyShapedMessageOrContext DoParse(IDictionary<string, string> commonDataFormat)
    {
        //TODO: parse the common data into the strongly typed message            
    }
}
```

**Factory**

```
public static class WorkflowFactory
{
    public static IGenericWorkflow Get(WorkflowType workflow) 
    {
        //TODO: find the concrete workflow by inspecting attributes
    }
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this could be driven by a UI or some contextual data
        var someSortOfWorkflowIdentifier = (WorkflowType)args[0];
        var data = GetSomeDictionaryOfData();

        var workflow = WorkflowFactory.Get(someSortOfWorkflowIdentifier);

        workflow.Process(workflow.Parse(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: C# supports attributes.

Comment: @HansPassant So does Java.

Comment: I would call this terrible design smell pattern. Instead of doing proper OOP, you are hacking something with generics.

Comment: @Euphoric What would you do differently?

Comment: @HansPassant if the metadata needs to change at runtime, an interface is great. especially if a portion of the metadata needs to be localised

Comment: @HansPassant I actually often use this with a plugin pattern using attributes on the concrete implementation which the factory then uses. I've edited to show you an example attribute and how the factory might use it

Comment: @Euphoric why is it bad? I have found this pattern useful in some cases and it does have some sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's exactly same as you named it: [Marker interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern)

Comment: Does everyone else agree on this? Before I accept I want to make sure. I know the empty interface I'm using as criteria for the generic argument is a marker interface, but it seems like there is more of a pattern than just that. Like the use of the abstract generic base to map marker interfaces into concrete types and then the ability to create concrete implementations with methods that accept different types of parameters but can still be called via a single common interface.

Comment: The other thing is that sometimes its not even a marker interface, sometimes you have a base Message or Context class with common fields, but the rest of the pattern stays identical, in terms of setting up the type-agnostic interface and then a generic base underneath it.